# How to copy filename with tilde in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-nt

I have a DVD which should be burnt in year 2009.  In a directory there are 2 files.  File-1 is named abc~1.TXT with size 512 KB.  File-2 is named abcdefg.txt with size 43 KB.

Now using Win7, when I try to copy file-1 to my hard-disk, it will actually copy the data content of file-2.  The file name in hard-disk is the file name of file-1, but the size is 43 KB and the content is the same as file-2.

When I open file-1 in the DVD using notepad++, the content is the content of file-2.  Also, look like there is not 512 KB.

I also try the copy command in CMD prompt, but no luck, same behavior.

I also try to use 7zip to zip file-1, again 43 KB (not 512 KB) is zipped inside the zip file.

I search the internet.  Some tell me that file-1 may be the short file name situation working in Win NT.

My questions are :

1. How can I PROVE that file-1 is the short file name of file-2 ?  In this case, how can I look at the CONTENT of this 512 KB ?  There is no debug command in Win7 to look at the 512 KB byte-by-byte.
2. How about, if file-1 is NOT the short file name of file-2, how can I copy the TRUE CONTENT of file-1 (i.e. the 512 KB file content) to the hard-disk ?

Thanks in advance.
Alvin SIU

Comment: Did you try `dir /X` in CMD prompt to find whether _file-1 is the short file name of file-2_?

Comment: The filesystem on the DVD is corrupt if "ABCDEF~1.TXT" is the short name of "abcdefghi.txt" and also the primary name of a different file in the same directory. This should not be possible to create by normal means.

Comment: @JosefZ Try dir /X.  No Luck.  Same result as dir

Comment: @eryksun Using dir to have a look. There are a total of 4 files in the directory.  Three of them have same prefix in the file names. The file modification date-time of file-1 is the SAME as file-3 (which is 199 KB).  File-2 and file-3 are without TILDE char in the name.  The names of file-2 and file-3 are longer than 8-byte.

Comment: Run `fsutil file queryfileid <filename>` to get the ID of a file. In CMD, you can do this for every file in a directory via `for %f in (*) do @(echo %f & fsutil file queryfileid "%f")`.